# Select in a PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do my first Function in PostgreSQL, but I can't to do it.
I was write this piece of code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getCars () 
   RETURNS TABLE (
      car_name VARCHAR,
      id_car INT
) 
AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT
      brand,car_id
   FROM
      cars;
end;
$$ 

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But... The error is when I'm trying to call taht function:

```
SELECT getcars();
```

Where is the issue?

the error message it's:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function getcars() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. apparently `brand` is defined as `text`, not `varchar`
2. set returning functions have to be used like a table in the `FROM` clause.

So you need to change your function definition to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getcars() 
   RETURNS TABLE (car_name text, id_car INT) 
AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY 
   SELECT brand,car_id
   FROM cars;
end;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then use it like this:

```
select *
from getcars();
```

---

Simple functions that just return a query are better defined as `language sql`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getcars() 
   RETURNS TABLE (car_name text, id_car INT) 
AS $$
   SELECT brand,car_id
   FROM cars;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql
stable;
```